# Is it possible to use timeout without delayed?

Tags: dart

I am just trying to understand how timeout works in Futures, but I can't interrupt anything a litle more complex. Look at this really simple code , I thought that it would get an exception if that loop take longer than 1 second but it does not happen. Anyone could please explain what happens here?

I am trying using this tool: https://dartpad.dartlang.org/

```
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  new Future(() {
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < 500000000; i++) {
      sum += i;
    }
    return sum;
  }).timeout(new Duration(seconds: 1)).then(print).catchError(print);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all `Future.timeout` does not interrupt any computation.
It creates a *new* `Future` which completes either with the value of the original `Future`, or with the result of timing out, if the original future didn't complete in time. It's more like it takes two futures: The original one and one created using `Future.delayed`, and then creates a third `Future` which will complete with the result of the *first* the other two to complete.

There is no signal going back to the computation which will eventually complete the original future. It will not stop unless you make it stop.

The use-case for `Future.timeout` is, say, a network connection that doesn't appear to give a result in time. You can't stop that request, but you can stop waiting for the answer, which is what `timeout` does.

What happens in your example is:

- You create a `Future`, *f1* with the `Future` constructor. This schedules a *timer* with zero duration to call the argument function.
- You then call `timeout` on *f1*. This starts a timer with a duration of one second, and returns a future *f2*.
- You then call `then` on *f2* with `print` as argument. This puts a listener on *f2* and returns a future *f3*.
- You then call `catchError` on *f3* which puts an error listener on *f3* and returns a future *f4* (which is then ignored).
- Then control returns to the event loop, and the next event is the zero-duration timer.
- The argument to the `Future` constructor is called. It counts to 500000000, then returns a value *v* and completes *f1* with that.
- The result of *f1* is propagated to *f2* which also completes with *v*.
- The result of *f2* is printed by `print`, and *f3* completes with *null*.
- The result of *f4* is ignored by the `catchError` and *f4* completes with *null*.
- Then control returns to the event loop. The next event is the 1-second timer started by `Future.timeout`. More than one second may have passed already, but this is the earliest opportunity for it to run.
- The `Future.timeout` timer callback sees that *f2* is already completed and does nothing.
- Control returns to the event loop, and since it is empty, the program ends.

Comment: Thanks, great explanation. Maybe I need to open other question cause I need to stop this future, I am using it for a listener UDP and sometimes  there is no results from device.

Answer (score 1):

i think you need to call this way timeout(Duration timeLimit, onTimeout());

so timeout(new Duration(seconds: 1),printFunction())

```
import 'dart:async';
_onTimeout() => print("Time Out occurs");
void main() {
  new Future(() {
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < 500000000; i++) {
      sum += i;
    }
    return sum;
  }).timeout(new Duration(seconds: 1),onTimeout: _onTimeout());
}
```

Comment: Would be onTimeout an event? Perhaps you could have a link with an exemple of use.

Comment: just do this way

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not working because your future value is being processing synchronously, so the event loop cannot process anything else but the for loop you're running. I suggest to read through these articles to understand better https://medium.com/hackernoon/are-futures-in-dart-threads-2cdc5bd8063a   https://medium.com/dartlang/dart-asynchronous-programming-isolates-and-event-loops-bffc3e296a6a of Futures and the event loop works.
A quick fix to your issue would be to use dart Isolates (together with the package:isolate library), for example:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:isolate/isolate.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  var isolate = await IsolateRunner.spawn();
  var value = await isolate.run(func, null, timeout: Duration(seconds: 1));
  print(value);
}

int func(_) {
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < 500000000; i++) {
    sum += i;
  }
  return sum;
}
```

It will throw a TimeoutException if the func() takes more than 1 second to complete, you can set an `onTimeout` function to be run when the timeout is hit.

Comment: Thanks Mattia, I'll try it.